# If $\int_0^1 x^n d\mu = 0$ for $n = 0, 1, 2, 3, ...$ then $\mu = 0$

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to solve this problem:

Let $\mu$ be a finite, Borel measure on $[0, 1]$ and suppose that
$$\int_0^1 x^n d\mu = 0$$
for $n = 0, 1, 2, 3, ...$.

Show that $\mu = 0.$

I assume that the question allows $\mu$ to be signed, otherwise the problem is trivial.

One potential strategy is clear: show that $\mu(I) = 0$ for any open interval $I \subseteq [0, 1],$ which implies that the measure of open set is zero. Then by outer regularity, we get that $\mu = 0.$ However, I haven't been able to show that $\mu(I) = 0.$ I tried using the Jordan Decomposition Theorem to write $\mu = \rho_+ - \rho_-$ with $\rho_+ \perp \rho_-$, but no luck.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Doesn't this follow simply from the positivity of $x^2$ in the $n = 2$ case?

Comment: How do you define the integral?

Comment: @StephenDonovan Well the measure can be signed (negative on some sets) so even if the function is positive and the integral is zero, it doesn't necessarily mean that the measure is zero.

Comment: @RolazaroAzeveires It's $\int f d \mu := \int f d\rho_+ - \int f d \rho_-$ where the $\rho's$ are from the Jordan decomposition of the measure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $L(f)=\int_{[0,1]}fd\mu$ for $f\in C[0,1]$. We are to show that $L=0$, in other words, $L(f)=0$ for any $f\in C[0,1]$.

Consider the set
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{D}=\{f\in C[0,1]: L(f)=0\}.
\end{align*}
If $f$ is a polynomial, then $L(f)=0$, and hence $\mathcal{D}$ contains all the polynomials. Therefore, $\mathcal{D}$ is dense in $C[0,1]$.

Now we note that
\begin{align*}
|L(f)|\leq\int_{[0,1]}|f|d|\mu|\leq|\mu|([0,1])\cdot\|f\|_{C[0,1]},
\end{align*}
this implies $L$ is continuous on $C[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I would upvote, but it seems I do not have enough points to do so. So $L$ is continuous on $C[0, 1]$ and $0$ on a dense subset of $C[0, 1]$ so it is identically zero. From here, I guess that we want to approximate $\mathbb{1}_I$ (where $I$ is an open interval) by a sequence of continuous functions. Is there some sort of analogue of the Monotone Convergence Theorem for signed measures?

Comment: Use the formula that $|\mu|(1)=\sup_{0\leq f\leq 1, f\in C[0,1]}|\mu(f)|$ then you are done.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: In fact, once you know that $\int f d\mu=0$ for $f$ continuous, (Stone-Weierstrass working on $S^1$) you are done because following the OP's idea, you can approximate $\chi_{(a,b)}$ by continuous functions which gives the result on intervals, hence on all opens.

Comment: @Matematleta We can approximate indicator function $F$ by a sequence of continuous functions $F_n$, but how do we know that the integral of the $F_n's$ converges to the integral of $F$? Do we have such a theorem for signed measures?

Comment: On $S^1,\ x^n=e^{int}$ and $C(\mathbb T)$ is dense in the trig polynomials.

Comment: @Matematleta Oh right, thanks!